# Implementing interface by templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have this interface:

```
struct I
{
    virtual void f(int) = 0;
    virtual void f(float) = 0;
};
```

May I implemnt `I` using something similar to next class?

```
struct C : public I
{
    template<typename T>
    void f(T);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The template method *overloads* the original two methods (i.e. it's a different method with the same name). `C` still has two pure virtual functions.

Answer (score 2):

As properly pointed out by NPE, you can't do this directly. However, you still can avoid code duplication by delegation:

```
struct C : public I
{
    void f(int x) { f_internal(x); }
    void f(float x) { f_internal(x); }

private:
    template<typename T>
    void f_internal(T x) { do stuff with x; }
};
```

Comment: I already did this and it seems somehow stupid to have on template that does everything, but because I need to implement some interfaces to have all the functions calling the template...